# PHP Class Property/Method Synchronization

Tags: php, inheritance, object, extends

Revised - I have multiple class definitions spread across files (one class per file). What I'm trying to do is this; I have a class called `Master` which I create an instance of, and in turn the `Master` object creates instances of the rest of my defined classes. `Master` has all of my properties defined inside it.

In the instances that `Master` creates, I want to be able to use `Master`'s properties/methods straight from `$this` i.e `$this->methodInMaster`, without the need for passing `Master`'s object to the new instance, storing it, and calling `$this->MasterInstance->methodinMaster`. Is there any way to achieve this?

The `extends` keyword does not help me here at all; the classes that `Master` creates instances of will inherit the properties and methods of `Master`, but any changes these instances make to the properties of `Master` are not 'saved' in the `Master` object, just the object that made the changes. In other words, the changes aren't visible in any other class.

I believe this is a limitation of not making things static so that there are no 'instances', but is there a way to get around all this using the `call, set` and `get` magic methods?

Comment: Have you verified that's really the case? It goes against the whole idea of inheritance.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve but extending from class is only extending the methods and fields not instance of object. Maybe you should try with some design patterns link Proxy or Factory?

Comment: Viruzzo it's PHP's behaviour, I don't understand it either. Basically what I'm trying to do is I have many classes spread over multiple files. I've put most of my properties in one class, and I want to be able to access them in other classes through `$this->property` without having to refer to an instance. `__get(), __set() and __call` seem to be the way to go(?) but I can't figure out a way of doing this.

Comment: @Blake Seems like you may not know about: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php and/or http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: I'd rather not have anything static in my code Jack, because there will be multiple instances of *every* class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extends doesn't help you because it's not what you need: if you want a single object that is accessible by many instances, you want a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) (it *has* to be static, because the alternative is having some impractical form of sharing a single reference). For the structure you desire, you will need a Singleton that is *different* from the Master class, but it's accessed by it. Basically you workflow will be:

- implement your functionality in the singleton
- access the singleton in the methods of Master
- extend Master as usual

This way every call in a subclass will be "redirected" transparently to a call to the singleton. It's not very elegant to do this (as opposed to directly accessing the singleton in the subclasses), but it should work for your design.